# How to Insert JSON data into database

Tags: java, json, servlets

From my UI via ajax I am getting an JSON data Which I am trying to insert into my data base, about which I have no idea how can i do that, I know how to insert something in database using `prepared statements` but here in JSON case I am totally confused

This is my JSON which I am getting in my doPost

```
{"ImageData":[{"Counter":"Counter A","Name":"CountA1.jpg","IsActive":"Y"},{"Counter":"Counter A","Name":"CountA2.jpg","IsActive":"Y"}]}
```

servlet code -->

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
            String imageData = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(imageData);

}
```

now I want to store this in my db like [image: This]

Do i need to parse this JSON, how will i do `ps.setInt(index, 0);`, I am not getting any idea

**Edit/update**

As **@Anjana Senanayake** answer I am doing like this

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
        String imageData = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(imageData);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(imageData);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ImageData");

        JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray); // this one is throwing error 
// eror is `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray`
        String counter = innerObj.getString("Counter");
        String name = innerObj.getString("Name");
        String isActive = innerObj.getString("IsActive");

        System.out.println(counter);

    }
```

But it is throwing error at `JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray[0]);`  error is `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray`

Comment: It's a rather broad question, but if you're not restricted to servlets I recommend looking into Spring Boot and using Jackson annotations to map the JSON to a java object and using JPA annotations on that object to map it to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use org.json library to parse it and create JsonObject :-

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(imageData);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ImageData");
```

Now, use this object to get your values :-

```
JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray[0]);

String counter = innerObj.getString("Counter");
String name = innerObj.getString("Name");
String isActive = innerObj.getString("IsActive");
```

since it is an array of objects, you have do repeat above for all the elements in jsonObj.

Comment: how will i store the above json into my pojo?

Comment: You don't save it manually. ImageData.class is the type of the java object after your imageData is parsed from json to java using Gson. you have to write the ImageData.java POJO as mentioned in the @Yuri Kushch ans.

Comment: I am new to this not able to understand how will I parse that, and I have to save it through my doPost servlet method I am getting JSON there only, earlier I was using `requet.getParameter()` to get the values, but here my UI is not have form elements that's why facing issues

Comment: Yaa that is the main issue, i don't have all elements having form elements that's why I am getting a full JSON at one time

Comment: @viveksingh check the updated ans for how to get the values from input elements

Comment: can you show the output of this as well --> System.out.println(imageData);

Answer (score 2):

You have several options here. It depends on what you want to achieve :)

#### Quick and dirty

Save it as a string. You will have to create a new class with `String` object, then put your JSON data into this object and save it.

I realized that it's not going to work since it is not what you actually want :)

#### Better way to do that

Create a new class with all fields.

```java
// File: ImageData.java
public class ImageData {
    private String counter;
    private String name;
    private String isActiveJpg;

    // getters and setters
}

// File: Data.java
public class Data {
    private List<ImageData> imageDataList;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Having those classes in place you are ready to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library. Please take a look at the usage example for Jackson [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) and GSON [serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-serialization-guide) and [deserialization](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide).

#### Sidenote

I would recommend to rethink the design itself. E.g. the naming of the fields and the logic of the entity is quite misleading (things like `isActiveJpg`. It should be a `Set` and it should have a better naming like `isJpg` or something like that).

Comment: Sorry for that I have updated now  it is `isActive` only

Comment: Sir according to your 1st option, how can I achieve that as I am newbie in java not very new but if you help with some code for that then it will be very helpful or for second option also some more code will help me and I have to use servelt to save data as I am getting all the json inside servlet post method

Comment: Okay, I reread your question and you want the full structure to be saved into the database. Please, then use the example from the subsection **Better way to do that**. The first option is not what you want and need to do.

Comment: Sir I am working in servlet dopost there I am getting the json, now have to create one class where I have to set getter and setter of counter is active and name, then what after that?

Comment: After creating those classes, I would recommend to take a look and read the following articles:
- [GSON deserialization guide](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide)
- [GSON serialization guide](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-serialization-guide)
- [Reading and writing JSON data](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-in-java/)

Comment: The problem that you have in your edit is that you are trying to read an array, but you are trying to do that with `JSONObject`, but you should do it with `JSONArray`. I would still recommend you to go through the links that I've provided. It contains all the examples there :)